# dgeni document generation set is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package

My problem is that the dgeni doc generation crashes and I read the error set is not defined, so I think the error has something to do with that.

I have installed dgeni via npm install (currently under Windows 7 but also tried Ubuntu 14.04 before).
With that I mean:

- dgeni ~0.4.2
- dgeni-packages ~0.14.0
- canonical-path 0.0.2

In the public folder of the project there are a lot of .js files in. They are not directly in /public but some subfolders.

I set up a dgeni package like this in the docs folder and downloaded templates located in /docs/templates:

dgeni-docs.js

```js
var path = require('canonical-path');
var Package = require('dgeni').Package;

module.exports = new Package('dgeniDocsPackage', [
  require('dgeni-packages/dgeni'),
  require('dgeni-packages/jsdoc'),
  require('dgeni-packages/nunjucks')
])

.config(function(log, readFilesProcessor, writeFilesProcessor, templateFinder, debugDumpProcessor) {

  log.level = 'info';

  readFilesProcessor.basePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
  readFilesProcessor.sourceFiles = [{ include: 'public/**/*.js', basePath: 'public' }];
  writeFilesProcessor.outputFolder = 'docs/build';

  templateFinder.templateFolders.unshift('docs/templates');
  templateFinder.templatePatterns.unshift('common.template.html');
});
```

common.template.html

```html
<h1>{{ doc.codeName }} ({{ doc.outputPath }})</h1>
<p>{{ doc.description }}</p>

{%- if doc.params %}
<h2>Params</h2>
<ul>
{%- for param in doc.params %}
  <li>
    <strong>{{ param.name }}</strong> { {{ param.typeList }} } - {{ param.description }}
  </li>
{%- endfor %}
</ul>
{%- endif %}

{%- if doc.returns %}
<h2>Returns</h2>
<p>
  { {{ doc.returns.typeList }} } - {{ doc.returns.description }}
</p>
{%- endif %}
```

and the command I started it with is
"dgeni .\docs\dgeni-docs.js"

The output is:

```html
W:\home\webserver\aconcept (master) (aconcept@0.3.3)
λ dgeni .\docs\dgeni-docs.js

W:\home\webserver\aconcept\node_modules\dgeni-packages\jsdoc\services\transforms\extract-access.js:8
  extractAccessTransformImpl.allowedDocTypes = new Set(['property', 'method'])
                                                   ^
ReferenceError: Set is not defined
    at extractAccessTransform (W:\home\webserver\aconcept\node_modules\dgeni-packages\jsdoc\services\transforms\extract-access.js:8:52)
    at Array.invoke [as 0] (C:\Users\HSO4ABT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dgeni\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:75:15)
    at get (C:\Users\HSO4ABT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dgeni\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:48:43)
    at C:\Users\HSO4ABT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dgeni\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:71:14
    at Array.map (native)
    at invoke (C:\Users\HSO4ABT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dgeni\node_modules\di\lib\injector.js:70:31)
    at C:\Users\HSO4ABT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dgeni\lib\util\getInjectables.js:10:31
    at Array.map (native)
    at C:\Users\HSO4ABT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dgeni\lib\util\getInjectables.js:9:22
    at module.exports.Package.processor.processor.processor.processor.processor.processor.processor.processor.processor.factory.factory.factory.factory.factory.factory.factory.factory.factory.factory.config.config.config.extractTagsProcessor.defaultTagTransforms (W:\home\webserver\aconcept\node_modules\dgeni-packages\jsdoc\index.js:42:39)
```

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, the solution was to use gulp for the generation. Up to the documentation it should also be possible to call it in the console directly though.

Here a finished example for those of you who are interested in a complete one:
https://github.com/petebacondarwin/dgeni-example

Comment: Found myself running into a very similar problem, running with Gulp will help but ultimately my problem was an older NodeJs installation (v10.35 to be precise). I'm not sure what the minimum version of Node you'd need but it certainly worked once I installed the latest Node (v6.9.1 at the time of this comment).